# Regex to match one or two groups or both

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I want a regex that can match either one group, or two groups. Here is an example of how it looks. Either like this:

> (key)

Or like this:

> (key "value")

So far I've come up with an expression which matches the latter example. But I have no idea how to modify it so it matches either the first one, or the latter one. Here it is:

```
\((?P<property_key>[^() ]+) "(?P<property_value>[^"]*)"\)
```

Comment: Is `regex` the (entire) right answer for this? Why not simply match parenthesized expressions and then `split(x, 1)` them on whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for regex pattern

```
\((?P<property_key>\w+)(?:\s+"(?P<property_value>\w+)")?\)
```

Comment: Oh! How cleaver solution you came up with! Many thanks to you, it solved all my problems. May the force be with you, young padawan.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation?

Comment: @shaikmoeed: See "Explanation" on right top of https://regex101.com/r/1EiEQp/1